# How do I go about solving the integral of csc x?

Tags: calculus, integration

So **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325950/135944)** is a solution provided by another user a couple of years ago and I've seen this solution before but I'm not clear on how or why?

What would make me think or tip me off that I should multiply it the way that is shown?

Also it looks like there is a u-sub but I don't understand how it gets to the 1/u phase.

It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me understand the solution better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you comfortable with $u$ substitutions and derivatives of trig functions? Because that's all there is to that solution using a clever trick. There's also another way as well. There's no point on going further if you're not solid on those two. This is similar to finding the antiderivative of $\sec(x)$

Comment: @MathNewbie Yes, I am familiar on both, but working backwards with integration of trig functions that are not immediately obvious (because of derivatives I've memorized) is still something I'm working on.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah this and $\sec(x)$ are a bit tricky at first glance. I would have multiplied both the denominator and numerator by $\sin(x)$ and rewrite the denominator as $1-\cos^2(x)$ and use partial fraction decomposition if I didn't know the trick as shown in your link.

Answer (score 7):

Hoping that I am not of topic, there is a very simple way to compute this antiderivative : the tangent half-angle substitution $t=\tan(\frac x2)$.

So $$I=\int \csc (x)\,dx=\int \frac {dx}{\sin(x)}=\int \frac {dt}{t}=\log(t)=\log\Big(\tan\big(\frac x2\big)\Big)$$

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, am I to assume this is a natural log or is this different?

Comment: May I confess (don't repeat it) that I only know one logarithm ? Natural, for sure. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 6):

Claude Leibovici's answer gives the easiest way to integrate this.

Another method that's longer than the one you refer to, but is maybe easier to motivate, is to write

$\displaystyle\int\csc x\;dx=\int\frac{1}{\sin x}\;dx=\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin^2x}\;dx=\int\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos^2 x}\;dx$.

Now let $u=\cos x, \;du=-\sin xdx$ to get
$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{u^2-1}\;du$, and then use partial fractions.

Comment: Nice way ! By the way, you miss one $\int$ in the middle.

Comment: You're right, this is easier for me to wrap my head around although Claude Leibovici's is simpler. I will practice both, thank you!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for the comment, and the correction.

Answer (score 1):

$u=\csc(x)-\cot(x)$, so $du = \csc^2(x)-\cot(x)\csc(x) dx$.

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\csc^{2}(x)-\csc(x)\cot(x)}{\csc(x)-\cot(x)}dx &= \\  \int\frac{\csc^{2}(x)-\csc(x)\cot(x)}{u}\frac{1}{\csc^2(x)-\cot(x)\csc(x)} du &= \\ \int\frac{1}{u} du \end{align*}