# Integrate $1/(u^2 - 1)$ without partial fractions?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there any way possible that I might integrate
$$ \int\frac{1}{u^2-1}\,du $$ without appealing to partial fraction decomposition?

I am trying to work some interesting $u$-substitution integrals with novice students who do not need to be taught partial fraction decomposition.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't they need to be taught PFD?

Comment: consider trigonometry!

Comment: Hint: et $u = \sec t$.

Comment: @AndrewLi not an objective for their course. It is the end of the semester, I am trying to work a couple tough integrals to end the semester. All of my ideas have come back to PFD.

Comment: @clocktower Well, you could use trig identities to find the antiderivative as me and Karn's do, but IIRC isn't PFD standard precalculus curriculum (at least in US where I'm from)?

Comment: IMO, substitution is harder than partial fraction decomposition, which is just a matter of algebra, not calculus.

Comment: $u=\cosh x$ probably works just as well as $\sec x$, though I suppose hyperbolic functions may not be taught yet

Comment: Well, you may just write the numerator $1$ as $\frac{1}{2}\left[(1-u)+(1+u)\right]$, motivated by the fact that both $(1-u)$ and $(1+u)$ are divisors of the denominator $1-u^2$. It is actually the same as performing a partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 4):

This is motivated by the solution, so it works quite nicely. It is an alternative to the $\sec$ substitution that has been suggested.$$u=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$$ $$\frac1{u^2-1}=-\frac{4x}{(1+x)^2}\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,du=-\frac2{(1+x)^2}\,dx\\$$ so the integral becomes $$\int\frac1{2x}\,dx=\frac12\ln x$$

Answer (score 3):

The moment you see $$u^2-1$$
you should think of some trigonometric stuff.

So if you remember,

$$\tan^2x=\sec^2x-1$$

thus $$u=\sec x$$ surely is a candidate (and there are a lot of other variations to play around with!).

Comment: How would you go about integrating $\csc x$? This is what this would lead to. If I was given that, I'd probably end up coming back to this and using partial fractions..

Comment: @JohnDoe It's just $$-\ln(\csc x + \cot x)+C$$

You can always teach your student how this was derived since it's pretty manageable.

Answer (score 3):

Use trigonometric substitution as the integrand contains $u^2-a^2$ where $a=1$. Substitute $u = a\sec \theta$, or just $u = \sec \theta$.

$$u = \sec \theta\quad \mathrm du = \sec\theta\tan\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$$
$$\int {1\over \sec^2 \theta - 1} \sec\theta\tan\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$$

Which can be integrated by remembering the identity $\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2 \theta$:

$$\int {1\over \sec^2 \theta - 1} \sec\theta\tan\theta\,\mathrm d\theta = \int {\sec \theta \over \tan\theta}\mathrm d\theta = \int \csc \theta \,\mathrm d\theta$$

And you can find the antiderivative of $\csc \theta$ via identities, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325950/integral-of-cscx). Of course, this would be much easier via partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\frac{1}{1-u^2}=\frac{1}{(1+u)(1-u)}=\frac{1}{(1+u)(2-(1+u))}=\frac{1}{(1+u)^2\bigl(\frac{2}{1+u}-1\bigr)}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}\,du=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\biggl|\frac{2}{1+u}-1\biggr|+C.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided already show many different ways this integral can be approached without Partial Fractions. Here is one more. Similar to the trigonometric substitution $u = \sec(x)$ we can employ the [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) substitution $u = \tanh(x)$

\begin{align}
 \int \frac{1}{u^2 - 1}\:du &= \int \frac{1}{\tanh^2(x) - 1}\cdot -\operatorname{sech}^2(x)\:dx \\
&= \int \frac{1}{\operatorname{sech}^2(x)}\cdot -\operatorname{sech}^2(x)\:dx \\
&= -x + C = -\operatorname{arctanh(u)} + C
\end{align}

Where $C$ is the constant of integration.